# Why are there so many Nikkudot?

Tags: hebrew, aleph-bet-letters

[image]

1) Why does every vowel has more than one way to be written?

2) Does every nekkud has a slightly different pronunciation?

Comment: please keep posts to one question each. Please also consider reading through these links before reposting to help you focus on what information you still seek http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22586/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10370/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45484/759 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_vocalization

Comment: I didn't think writing 3 different posts would be better. Maybe someone can answer with a link explaining everything about nekkudot. Thanks for the links btw ;)

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited my answer. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @DoubleAA I deleted the question about the origin of nekkudot, now I'm only asking why there are so many. I think the question should be removed from [on hold].

Comment: You are asking your question based on a picture with no cited source. It might be better if you ask specific questions (in separate posts): What sounds do the nekudot make? Who uses which sounds for which nekudot? Why do Israelis use the same sound for multiple nekudot?

Comment: @LN6595 Who said anything about Israelis? Most Jews I know of make use of multiple Nekudot for the same sound.